# Code server nuxt not work after deployment

Tags: fetch, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, vercel, supabase

I have a problem that I've been try to resolve this, I am using nuxt 3 and auth supabase with module support. My fail code is run on app.vue and fetching '/api/auth/user' and in there I am using serverSupabaseUser() to get user, everything is fine on development localhost but when I deploy this on vercel with zero configuration with github, that code is not working and return empty string. I try to refresh this but still same so I switch to useSupabaseUser with client and everything work but with little downgrade on performance. Does anybody know what wrong with server code?

my fetch code

```
const { data: user } = await useFetch('/api/auth/user', {
          headers: useRequestHeaders(['cookie'])
     })
```

my server code

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
     const user = await serverSupabaseUser(event)
     return user
})
```

is only impact on auth server, other than this the fetched server is running normally, also access_token and refresh token is available on cookie and localstorage

I try using client and deploy and its work but performance is get bad, so I start to switch back using server and try to resolve this using chatGPT but not really help so I start searching on google and this website but not found so I started asking maybe someone will help thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It was working before with useFetch and I can get the user using serverSupabaseUser from my api. But now, it returns null. I'm not sure if my recent Nuxt 3 release upgrade is related to this.